# Adding AWS Cognito User Pool role using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-elasticsearch

I have deployed https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-service-with-cognito to my stack, and am trying to add a `master` group as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-walkthrough-iam

So I have added to the following https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-service-with-cognito/blob/master/lib/search-stack.ts#L50

```
diff --git a/lib/search-stack.ts b/lib/search-stack.ts
index 85de0c0..2493c92 100644
--- a/lib/search-stack.ts
+++ b/lib/search-stack.ts
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@

 import { Fn, Stack, Construct, StackProps, CfnParameter, CfnOutput } from '@aws-cdk/core';
 import { CfnDomain } from '@aws-cdk/aws-elasticsearch';
-import { UserPoolAttribute, CfnUserPoolDomain, CfnIdentityPool, CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment, CfnUserPool } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cognito';
+import { UserPoolAttribute, CfnUserPoolDomain, CfnIdentityPool, CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment, CfnUserPool, CfnUserPoolGroup } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cognito';
 import { Role, ManagedPolicy, ServicePrincipal, FederatedPrincipal } from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
 import { CustomResource } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation';

@@ -55,6 +55,19 @@ export class SearchStack extends Stack {
       }, "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity")
     });

+    // create two groups, one for admins one for users
+
+    new CfnUserPoolGroup(this, "AdminsGroup", {
+      groupName: "master-user-group",
+      userPoolId: idPool.ref,
+
+    });
+
+    new CfnUserPoolGroup(this, "UsersGroup", {
+      groupName: "limited-user-group",
+      userPoolId: idPool.ref,
+    });
+
     const esRole = new Role(this, "esRole", {
       assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('es.amazonaws.com'),
       managedPolicies: [ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonESCognitoAccess")]
~
```

but after redeploying the roles are not being created!

any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 1.1.1 the [amazon-elasticsearch-service-with-cognito code](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-service-with-cognito/blob/master/lib/search-stack.ts) includes the configuration for fine-grained access control, including an Amazon Cognito group called "es-admins", and the required role resolution.

Answer (score 7):

As of AWS CDK v1.91.0 the use the `userPoolId` instead of `ref`:

```js
import * as cognito from '@aws-cdk/aws-cognito';

//...

const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, 'UserPool', {
  //...
});

new cognito.CfnUserPoolGroup(this, "ManagerGroup", {
  groupName: "manager",
  userPoolId: userPool.userPoolId
});
```

Answer (score 6):

OK, I needed to use:

```
    new CfnUserPoolGroup(this, "AdminsGroup", {
      groupName: "master-user-group",
      userPoolId: userPool.ref
    });

    new CfnUserPoolGroup(this, "UsersGroup", {
      groupName: "limited-user-group",
      userPoolId: userPool.ref
    });
```

instead of `idPool.ref`

Comment: You beat me to it. Yesterday I saw that but I got side tracked and totally missed answering it. Thankfully you got it all sorted out !!